# ¿Como leer datos desde firebase a un html simple?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Hola chicos estoy intentando obtener los datos desde firebase,  a un html simple pero no me cargan los datos al solicitarlos
quiero que al ingresar un texto en el input "numero" este se vincule con childData['numero'] y me lo publique en p"data"
Alguien sabe como hacerlo funcionar?

```
 var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "***********************",
    authDomain: "*****************",
    databaseURL: "*********************",
    projectId: "***********",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "************",
    appId: "***************"
  };

 firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
 firebase.database().ref('User/').once('value', function(snapshot){
 snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot)
{
        var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = childData['numero'];


<input id="numero" type="text" value="">
<p id = "data"></p>
```

Comment: Estás realizando la conexión a firebase? El atributo `.value` es para los `<input />`, `<select>` y `<textearea>` y lo estás haciendo en una etiqueta `<p>`, en ese caso sería `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Seguro estas realizando la conexion con Firebase ? Aca te dejo un mini proyecto que tengo con Firebase para que chequees como es la conexion.
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://codesandbox.io/s/firebase-upload-read-music-vwfs2?fontsize=14)

Comment: hola kleith, si tienes razon es innerHTML pero aun asi chilData no obtiene el valor del input "numero"